# Ejecutar shell_exec en Kali Linux

Tags: php, python, linux

Estoy intentando ejecutar un programa de python en kali linux. El problema que no logro que me funcione el siguiente comando:

```
$output=shell_exec('sudo python3 sniffer.py -t '.$tiempo);
```

Al utilizar el comando sudo se que debo ingresar una contraseña, por eso modifique el archivo /etc/sudoers.temp con el comando sudo visudo y agregando en la ultima linea del archivo miusuario ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

En la consola no me aparece ningún error. Tengo instalado php7 y apache2

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" align="center">
    <form action='sniffer.php' method='get'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="timeInput">Tiempo de ejecución (sec)</label>
        <input type="number" value="10" class="form-control" id="timeInput" name="tiempo">
    </div>
    <?php
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
            if(isset($_GET["tiempo"])){
        try {
                $tiempo=$_GET["tiempo"];
                $output=shell_exec('sudo python sniffer.py -t '.$tiempo);
        echo $output;
                echo "<button class='btn btn-dark' type='submit'>Ejecutar sniffer</button>";
                echo "<div class='form-group'>
                <label for='comment'>Packet Trace:</label>
                <textarea class='form-control' rows='5' id='comment'>$output</textarea>
                </div>";     
        } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }          
            }else{
                echo "<button class='btn btn-dark' type='submit'>Ejecutar sniffer</button>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<button class='btn btn-dark' type='submit'>Ejecutar sniffer</button>";
        }
    ?>
    </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
  <style>
    .container{
        max-width:500px;
    }
  </style>
</html>
```

Al ejecutar el comando sudo python3 sniffer.py ejecuto el programa sniffer.py y que corra sobre la versión 3 de python.

En la pc me aparecen dos versiones de python, la 2.7 y la 3

python --version
Python 2.7.17

python3 --version
Python 3.7.6

No se si el tener dos versiones instaladas, pueda generarme el problema que tengo.

Comment: Dices que añadiste a *sudoers* la línea `miusuario ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`. Supongo que te refieres **al usuario que ejecuta PHP**, ¿ Verdad ?

Comment: @Trauma, el usuario que agregue es el mio, como puedo saber cual es el usuario que ejecuta php? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Haz `ps xa | less` para ver los procesos activos. Busca el servidor web o fpm (según como lo ejecutes). La primera columna es el PID del proceso. Ahora, ejecuta `stat -c "%u %g" /proc/PID_DEL_PROCESO/` y te saldrá el UID del usuario que lo corre. Y ya lo puedes buscar en `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @Trauma me ayudaste muchisimo, el usuario que ejecuta php era el que no tenía permisos, muy agradecido. Ya me funciono correctamente.

Comment: Pues ale, ya puedes auto-responderte para cuando le pase a otro :-)

Comment: Y no olvides indicar que permitir `sudo` **sin contraseña** al usuario que ejecutar PHP es una **muy mala idea** :-p